# Impersonation in MDriven?

Tags: mdriven

I am trying to build an “impersonate” page in order to “log in” as another user . I am thus trying to assign the CurrenUser with a vCurrent_XXXX value but the result is that the CurrentUser is set to null ? How do I control this?

Answer (score 0):

[image: MDriven SysUser login standard model]

MDriven Turnkey checks for the model pattern above and sets the CurrentUser-transient-link on MVC gets based on the IdentityProvider mechanism from the web app.

The MDriven Turnkey app then use the value of this transient link to decide what SysUser to handle as logged in.

Consider changing the CurrentUser transient link to a a ReverseDerived (and derived) link.
Then Turnkey logic can set it - and you can override it.

Add a transient link called ImpersonatedUser - let the derivation of CurrentUser return self.ImpersonatedUser - that would give the effect you want.